# How to check if input contains string if else condition?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

How to check if field1 or field2 (or both) contains "n" and input the letter n in field3 (if condition). Otherwise (else condition) calculate.

So i setup that code. It doesn't run for the if condition, its always using the else condition. I guess their is a mistake in my if condition. How to make it work?

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementById('field1');
  var inputa = document.getElementById('field2');
  var tot = 0;
  if (inputa == "n" || arr == "n") {
    document.getElementById('field3').value = "n";
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot = parseFloat(inputa[i].value) - parseFloat(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('field3').value = tot;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="field1" name="field1" onblur="findTotal()" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="field2" name="field2" onblur="findTotal()" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="field3" name="field3" />
```

Here is the code to try: https://jsfiddle.net/gpbdvnso/

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` is going to return a list of elements, not a single element. And your `if` statement is attempting to check that _list_ against a single value?

Comment: This class only exists 1 time. I could also write getElementById - so field1 only exists 1 time.

Comment: Yes, that's a good start. You could also add your HTML to your question *and* make a working example of your existing code, which would help people help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you :) I added a JsFiddle so everyone can try. I already changed ByClassName to ById. I got an idea: maybe one mistake is that I wrote "var arr" because arr can be a letter or a number.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `arr.length`, `arr[i]`, and `inputa['i']` ?? `arr` and `inputa` are DOM elements.

Comment: Basically I want to calculate: value of field2(input) minus value of field1 (arr) -> input value in field3. But if user types "n" then "n" should be displayed in field3 and no calculation should start. The calculation byiteself works perfectly. But since I startet to make an if / else condition because of this nee possibility to enter "n" it doesn't work to calculate nor about the "n".

Comment: Lose the loop wrapper: `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { ... }`. Just execute what's in the loop block. And just use `arr.value` and `inputa.value` to access the potential integers. And since you're only allowing a single character `parseInt()` ought to work just fine.

Comment: Awesome! So calculation works now: https://jsfiddle.net/8dcf93u1/ . But the if I input "n" in field1 or field2 or both it doesn't show "n" in field3

Comment: `inputa` and `arr` are DOM elements, use `inputa.value` and `arr.value`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that. I changed the names of parameters but no effort https://jsfiddle.net/8dcf93u1/1/ , I used the NaN function now but also no effort: https://jsfiddle.net/8dcf93u1/3/ - he prints n that's good for the first time but no calculation anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few points still unclear, but maybe the following is a pointer of where you could go? I collected all the DOM elements in a collection and then assigned the elements to the variables `a`, `b` and `sum` (a de-structuring assignment).

```js
function findTotal() {
  const [a,b,sum] = document.querySelectorAll('input');  
  sum.value=a.value=="n"||b.value=="n"?"n":+a.value+(+b.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="field1"  name="field1" onblur="findTotal()" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="field2"  name="field2" onblur="findTotal()" />
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="field3"  name="field3" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks really professional. I took your advice and bloodyKnuckles advices now. Problem is I can't query all inputs as their are more then 100 more which have no connection to that. To change it to that: so the result is NaN. So as you both saying the problem is the Dom operator. Still the "n" isn't the result :/  https://jsfiddle.net/6rk2cged/

Comment: Well, the idea is to find a _pattern_ behind the inputs you are interested in. Maybe a class name? Or a parent DOM element they are grouped in? That way you can then select them a bit more specifically in order to apply the "magic".

Comment: That's great, didn't thought that way before, I appreciate your answer and will try to find a way. Thank you very much.